# Fixing an error with assigning of empty list to value "DNA_Sequence"

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, bioinformatics, dna-sequence, index-error

So, this question is the continuation of previous post [Python-script, which should translate 1000 DNA-Sequences to proteins by 1152 different codontables, don't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49653119/python-script-which-should-translate-1000-dna-sequences-to-proteins-by-1152-dif). From that time I have edited script in PyCharm and now this script has such look:

```
import yaml
file = open('/home/ihor/Документи/біоінформатика/DNA_Sequence72 - Копія.py', 'r')
DNA = file.read()
DNA_Sequences = DNA.split(',')
Genetic_Codes = open('/home/ihor/Документи/біоінформатика/Genetic_Codes.py', 'r')
Genetic_Codes = Genetic_Codes.read()
Genetic_Codes_list = Genetic_Codes.split('\n')
for row in range(1152): #for str in list[Genetic_Codes_list] in range(1152):
    Alternative_Genetic_Codes = Genetic_Codes_list.pop(0)
    for line in range(1000):
        dna = DNA_Sequences.pop(0)
        codontable = yaml.load(Alternative_Genetic_Codes)
        codontable_sequence = ""
        for i in range(0, len(dna)-(3 + len(dna) % 3), 3):
            if codontable.get(dna[i:i + 3], codontable_sequence) == "_":
                break
            codontable_sequence += codontable.get(dna[i:i + 3], codontable_sequence)
        print(list([codontable_sequence]))
```

And now this script has only one error:

> IndexError: pop from empty list

After researching of variables in Debugger, I saw, what variable `DNA_Sequences` in line `DNA_Sequences = DNA.split(',')` was assigned value '[] (empty list)'. My script translate the list of strings of 1000 DNA-Sequences to protein only by 1 codontable (dictionary), but I want, what this script translate the list of strings of 1000 DNA-Sequences to proteins by 1152 different codontables on one run. I read a lot of tutorials and other sources about this error, lists etc.,but I didn't find any solution for my problem. All other variables are fully alright. How I can fix this error with empty list? I will be really thankfull for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pop` removes items from an array, so the first iteration of your outer loop creates an empty array. The solution is to access array items by index without removing them:

```
for line in range(1000):
    dna = DNA_Sequences[line]
```

Comment: I am sincerelly thankful for your brilliant tip! You rescued my bioinformatics project) It's work!

Answer (score 0):

Your code makes no sense. But nonetheless the answer is to check if the element is empty, if so pass.

```
for row in range(1152): #for str in list[Genetic_Codes_list] in range(1152):
    Alternative_Genetic_Codes = Genetic_Codes_list.pop(0)
    for line in range(1000):
        if len(DNA_Sequences) == 0:
            pass
        else:
            dna = DNA_Sequences.pop(0)
            codontable = yaml.load(Alternative_Genetic_Codes)
            codontable_sequence = ""
            for i in range(0, len(dna)-(3 + len(dna) % 3), 3):
                if codontable.get(dna[i:i + 3], codontable_sequence) == "_":
                    break
                codontable_sequence += codontable.get(dna[i:i + 3], codontable_sequence)
            print(list([codontable_sequence]))
```

You should really use `biopython` or similar.